# Data not posting.. Help! html,js,firebase

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to post data onto firebase, but it is not being posted..
I tried using addEventListener to have the data to be posted, but with no avail.
This is my html, with external main.js that includes the firebase sdk:

```
<BODY>
<TABLE align="center">
    <caption></caption>
    <tr>
        <td width=500 height=150 colspan=8 style="text-align: center"><strong
            style="font-size:50">Add an Entry</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <TD height=500 colspan=8>

            <form id="info">
                <table align="center">

                    <tr>
                        <td>Name:</td>
                        <th><INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="35"
                            Name="personal-name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name Here">
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <th><INPUT type="text" Size="40" Maxlength="40"
                            Name="personal-email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Here">
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>
                        <th><textarea rows="5" width="550" type="text" Size="40"
                                Maxlength="40" Name="address" id="address"
                                placeholder="__"></textarea>
                        </th>

                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
                <div align="center">
                    <button id="refresh">refresh</button>
                    <button id="addBtn" >submit</button>
                </div>

            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</Table>
</Body>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>    </BODY>
```

And this is my main.js:

// Firebase configuration, then eventlistener

```
var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: ******************************,
authDomain: ******************************,
databaseURL: ******************************,
projectId: ******************************,
storageBucket: ******************************,
messagingSenderId: ******************************,
appId: ******************************,
measurementId: ******************************,
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
firebase.firestore().collection("information").add({
    name:document.getElementById('name').value,
    email:document.getElementById('email').value,
    address:document.getElementById('address').value
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 things:

Make sure you define a form variable using the form's id

```
const form = document.getElementById("info");
```

You are missing the analytics and firestore sdk src (I included auth incase you plan to use it)

```
<!-- Firebase App (the core Firebase SDK) is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<!-- If you enabled Analytics in your project, add the Firebase SDK for Analytics -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<!-- Add Firebase products that you want to use -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.16.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
```

In your firebase console, change your database rules' conditional to true (if not already)

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

For performance, you should store your product initializations and collections in variables

```
const analytics = firebase.analytics();

const firestore = firebase.firestore(); 
const information = firestore.collection("information"); 

const form = document.getElementById("info");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e)=>{
  e.preventDefault();
  information.add({
    name:document.getElementById('name').value,
    email:document.getElementById('email').value,
    address:document.getElementById('address').value
  })
});
```

Alternatively, you can create a doc with a name for faster querying

```
information.doc(document.getElementById('name').value).set({
    name:document.getElementById('name').value,
    email:document.getElementById('email').value,
    address:document.getElementById('address').value
 })
```